# Navigation in react native with TouchableOpacity

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

I am currently working on a react native app. I am new to javascript and react. The main problem with this code is that touching the taskitem doesn't change the page while touching the task components warps to the all the other screens.

This first part is the Task.js file:

```js
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet, Image, Animated } from 'react-native';
import Cerebelum  from './Cerebelum';
import Cerebrum  from './Cerebrum';
import Brainstem  from './Brainstem';
import Structure  from './Structure';
import Physiology  from './Physiology';
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

let TheBigList = {
  Cerebrum: Cerebrum,
  Cerebelum: Cerebelum,
  Brainstem: Brainstem,
  Structure: Structure,
  Physiology: Physiology,
}

LogBox.ignoreLogs([
  'Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state',
]);

const TaskItem = ({ task, onPress }) => {
  const positionY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const translateY = positionY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, -20], // Adjust the falling distance of each task
  });

  const opacity = positionY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0],
  });

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.taskItemContainer}>
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          styles.taskItem,
          {
            transform: [{ translateY }],
            opacity,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Text style={styles.taskText}>{task}</Text>
      </Animated.View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const Task = ({ text, imagesrc, elem }) => {
  const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(true);

  const positionY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const handlePross = () => {
    setIsPressed(!isPressed);
    console.log('3');
  };

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleTaskPress = (task) => {
    console.log('4');
    navigation.navigate(task, { item: TheBigList[task] });
  };

  const renderTaskList = () => {
  const taskItems = elem; // Example task items

  return taskItems.map((task, index) => (
    <TaskItem key={index} task={task} onPress={handleTaskPress(task)} />
  );
};

return (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePross}>
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <View style={styles.square}>
        <Image source={imagesrc} style={styles.square} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.itemLeft}>
        <Text style={styles.itemText}>{text}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.circular} />
      {isPressed && <View style={styles.taskList}>{renderTaskList()}</View>}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

This second is the navigation.js part:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import Brainstem from './Brainstem';
import Cerebrum from './Cerebrum';
import Cerebelum from './Cerebelum';
import Structure from './Structure';
import Physiology from './Physiology';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Cerebrum" component={Cerebrum} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Cerebelum" component={Cerebelum} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Brainstem" component={Brainstem} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Structure" component={Structure} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Physiology" component={Physiology} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

I tried using a condition so that the rendering and the function don't happen at the same time, but the main issue here is that the taskitems remain unresponsive.

Comment: can you remove all the extra slashes from your code snippets please?  the code as written won't parse.  Also consider using a code formatter to line up your indentation etc

Comment: Try change the onPress function in `<TaskItem />` to `onPress={() => handleTaskPress(task)}`

Comment: @abe  I would love to but when I try to do so  I lose the highlighting. yes changing the placement of the handleTaskPress wound up being the right solution.

Comment: I formatted your code, please do not add slashes, it breaks the formatting.

Comment: thanks a lot @Abe. the thing is those slashes appeared when i copy pasted my code in the post. had no intention of adding them.

Answer (score 0):

This is the main change that I made:

```js
const positionY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
const navigation = useNavigation();

const gop = () => {
    navigation.navigate(task + "", { item: task });
};

const translateY = positionY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, -20], // Adjust the falling distance of each task
});

const opacity = positionY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0],
});

return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.taskItemContainer} onPress={gop}>
        <Animated.View
            style={[
                styles.taskItem,
                {
                    transform: [{ translateY }],
                    opacity,
                },
            ]}
        >
            <Text style={styles.taskText}>{task}</Text>
        </Animated.View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);};
```